# Bot not available for 1 on 1 chat in MS Teams

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am testing a chat bot (built using MS bot framework) in MS teams.  The bot is designed for one on one chat but I want to make it available to a group of testers.  As such, I've created a team and added the testers as members and the bot as an app.  According to the MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/apps-upload) my understanding was that if the bot manifest included 'personal' in the scope then any team member should be able to start one on one chat with the bot.  However, when searching for the bot in the "to" field of the Chat window some team member can find the bot and others can't.  My first thought was that there was delay between when a person was added to the team and when they could access the bot in a one on one chat.  But that doesn't seem to be the case.   Is there something else I've overlooked that would prevent the bot from showing up for some team members but not others?

Comment: All users in the team should be able to "@mention" the bot. Is that not working?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, yes team members can '@mention' the bot in the teams channel.  However, only some of them can start a one on one chat with the bot outside the team

Comment: Perhaps a Policy is at play... is it possible your O365 tenant admin has something set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Moe Adding the Bot to a team does not make the bot available to all the members of the team in personal scope. It is still in the teams scope and all the team members will be able to access the bot in the team only. A member of the team should either install the app in personal scope or click on the chat icon by hovering on the bot name in team and click on "Add"

Answer (score 0):

@Gousia-MSFT's answer got me part way to a solution.  When hovering over the bot's icon in the Teams chat I didn't get an option to 'add' the bot.  However, there was an option to 'chat' with the bot:
[image: Chat icont].  Using the text box or clicking the chat icon starts (or continues) a one on one conversation with the bot.